# Progress bar does not fit the background drawable

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-seekbar

I'm working on a horizontal progress bar and the progress does not seem to be fitting the drawable image. It starts after like 5dp.

This is my code.

```
<SeekBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="1070dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:background="@drawable/progress_bar"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_style" />
```

My seekbar style.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dip" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#ff0a75b0"
                android:startColor="#ff0a75b0" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dip" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#ff0a75b0"
                android:startColor="#ff0a75b0" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe: `android:layout_width="match_parent"` ?

Comment: No match parent doesnt seem to be working. the drawable length seems to be shrinking. It is not even a 9 patch. No idea. Why!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"               
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable" />
```

progress_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@android:id/background">
     <shape>
          <corners android:radius="10dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
     </shape>
 </item>
 <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
 <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
     <clip
         android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
         android:gravity="left">
         <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/greenStart"
                    android:centerColor="@color/greenMid"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="@color/greenEnd"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
     </clip>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Good answer) Maybe, you know how can I set height of progress line ? In your example progress line match all SeekBar height, but I need thin progress line.